# Count of states in a particular column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, coding-style, aggregation, lapply, sapply

I have a dataframe --> "test"

```
> test
     V1 V2
1 INS01  1
2 INS01  1
3 INS02  1
4 INS03  2
5 INS03  3
6 INS04  4
> class(test)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I wanted a count of "INS01", "INS02", "INS03", "INS04". I tried using "by" but it is not giving me the desired output.

```
> agg <- by(test, test$V1, function(x) length(x))
> agg
test$V1: INS01
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
test$V1: INS02
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
test$V1: INS03
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
test$V1: INS04
[1] 2
```

I am stuck here. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column V1 to a `factor` and use the default `factor` `summary` method, which returns frequencies.

```
> summary(as.factor(test$V1))
INS01 INS02 INS03 INS04
    2     1     2     1
```

Comment: Thanku... This is the most simplest solution. I was thinking the hard way :D

Comment: err... that's a useful solution, not the most simple :-)

Comment: I must agree with @JorisMeys here, but then again, I didn't ask the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `table()`

Let's make the test data frame (and please give similar code in your next questions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

```
zz <- textConnection("
V1 V2
1 INS01  1
2 INS01  1
3 INS02  1
4 INS03  2
5 INS03  3
6 INS04  4
")
Data <- read.table(zz)
```

And then:

```
> table(Data$V1)

INS01 INS02 INS03 INS04 
    2     1     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Joris shares the way I would go about doing this, but I thought I would share why your answer is wrong:

Using `length` on a `data.frame` tells you how many columns there are in a `data.frame`, not the number of resulting rows (which is what you're actually after).

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:100, ncol = 25))
length(x)
# [1] 25
```

If you want to use `by`, use `nrow` instead:

```
by(test, test$V1, function(x) nrow(x))
# test$V1: INS01
# [1] 2
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# test$V1: INS02
# [1] 1
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# test$V1: INS03
# [1] 2
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# test$V1: INS04
# [1] 1
```